# Filter array object by array of Boolean values dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have my array object in the following format

```
menuItem = [{
    "name": "MOZZARELLA DI BUFALA & TOMATOES",
    "gluten": true,
    "eggs": false,
    "dairy": true,
     ...
},...
```

I want to filter hundreds of menuItems by the allergen values (Boolean).

While the following code does the trick:

```
menuItem.filter(el => !el.gluten && !el.fish && !el.soy && !el.dairy)"
```

The allergens are hardcoded and repetitive. I am struggling to make the code dynamic and elegant.

I tried the following solution

```
menuItem.filter(el => !el[allergens])"
var allergens = ['gluten', 'fish', 'soy', 'dairy']
```

However, it only works correctly with one allergen value. Multiple values as in the above example do not filter anything.

Comment: `menuIten.filter(el => Object.keys(el).filter(i => (typeof i === "boolean").every(i => !i));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), whichever match your case

```
const allergens = ['gluten', 'fish', 'soy', 'dairy']

const res = menuItem.filter(
  (el) => !allergens.every((allergen) => el[allergen])
);
// equivalent to `menuItem.filter(el => !el.gluten && !el.fish && !el.soy && !el.dairy)`
```

```js
const menuItem = [
  {
    name: 'dish A',
    gluten: true,
    fish: true,
    soy: true,
    dairy: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'dish B',
    gluten: true,
    fish: true,
    soy: false,
    dairy: true,
  },
];

const allergens = ['gluten', 'fish', 'soy', 'dairy'];

const res = menuItem.filter(
  (el) => !allergens.every((allergen) => el[allergen])
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code seems to have the same problem as my original example with multiple allergen values. If you add one more dish to your example and filter them with multiple allergen values, it will only filter the first allergen in the array correctly. –

Comment: Using .some instead of .every did the trick

Answer (score 2):

First extract the name property, then check that the rest of the properties in the object are falsey.

```
menuItem.filter(
  ({ name, ...rest }) => Object.values(rest).every(val => !val)
);
```

Ideally, I'd prefer to restructure the input array so the allergies are in a separate property, perhaps:

```
menuItem = [{
    "name": "MOZZARELLA DI BUFALA & TOMATOES",
    allergens: {
        "gluten": true,
        "eggs": false,
        "dairy": true,
```

to make accessing them easier.

```
menuItem.filter(
  ({ allergens }) => Object.values(allergens).every(val => !val)
);
```